# How to delete those punctuation?

Tags: java, string, replaceall

```
    public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "so many, punctuations , haha!";
        a.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}]+", "");
        System.out.print(a);
    }
}
```

I try this method, but the punctuation in a is still there, I don't understand why.

The replaceAll() function didn't work.

Comment: It is replaced, but you need to assign the return value of the replaceAll function, since String class is immutable.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot String is immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
a = a.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}]+", "");
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot String is immutable :p

Answer (score 3):

`a.replaceAll()` creates a brand new string, which you promptly ignore.

You probably want to assing this new string to `a`.